# Java Application not loading/downloading full application using JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp

I am launching a Java Application using a batch file using this command:

```
SET JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-agentpath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jacada\JIA\2.2\JavaAgent" -Djava.ext.dirs="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jacada\JIA\2.2\JavaSupport" -Xdebug -Djia.port=5000:5060 -Dlog4j.configuration="jia.log4j.properties"

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -noframemerging http:///linktofile/jnlpfile.jnlp
```

The application does not fully load.

Comment: Do you get any message in the debug console ? What do you mean with "not fully load", the app doesn't start ?

Comment: Please post any error-message from your java-console. And I'm pretty sure we'll need to see the jnlp-file as well.

Comment: The debug console basically just shows the commands executed in the batch file

Comment: I cannot post the JNLP file contents because of privacy issues

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this batch file template:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET JAVA_BASE=C:\PROGRA~2\Java\JRE18~1.0_1
SET JAVA_BIN=%JAVA_BASE%\bin
SET JAVA_EXT=%JAVA_BASE%\lib\ext
SET JNLP=https://server/webstart-app.jnlp
SET JIA_BIN=C:\PROGRA~2\Jacada\JIA

SET JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-Dlog4j.configuration=jia.log4j.properties -agentpath:%JIA_BIN%\JavaAgent -Djia.port=4444:4460 -Djava.ext.dirs=%JIA_BIN%\JavaSupport;%JAVA_EXT%
SET PATH=%JAVA_BIN%

REM Go to the [JRE]/lib/security folder, edit the following files:
REM     java.policy,
REM     javaws.policy
REM Make sure the have the following lines inside the general 'grant' block:
REM     permission java.awt.AWTPermission "listenToAllAWTEvents"; 
REM     permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessEventQueue";
REM     permission java.awt.AWTPermission "setDropTarget";
REM     permission java.awt.AWTPermission "accessClipboard";
REM     permission java.awt.AWTPermission "acceptDropBetweenAccessControllerContexts";

ECHO JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=%JAVAWS_VM_ARGS%
ECHO.
ECHO PATH=%PATH%
ECHO.
ECHO COMMAND="%JAVA_BIN%\javaws.exe" -verbose "%JNLP%"
ECHO.
"%JAVA_BIN%\javaws.exe" -verbose "%JNLP%"
```

<sub>* Disclaimer: I work for Jacada</sub>